# Is an applicationserver allowed to call the `valueUnbound(..)` method twice during session invalidating for an object which is bound to a session?

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, websphere-liberty

I have a web application (Servlet 2.4 specification) which runs fine on Websphere 8.0, 8.5 and Tomcat 8.5. Now we want to evaluate if the appcliation can be run under Websphere Liberty.

The Websphere logfile delivers the following version numbers during startup:

```
product = WebSphere Application Server 17.0.0.2 (wlp-1.0.17.cl170220170523-1818)
```

During the start of the application by sending the start URL in the browser, some objects are bound to the session. For example by the following code:

```
(...)
GwgImpl gwg = (GwgImpl)session.getAttribute(WEBKEY);
if (gwg == null) {
  gwg = new GwgImpl();
  session.setAttribute(WEBKEY, gwg);
}
(...)
```

The `GwgImpl` object is defined by the following:

```
public class GwgImpl implements HttpSessionBindingListener {
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  (...)
  public void valueBound(HttpSessionBindingEvent ev) {
  }

  public void valueUnbound(HttpSessionBindingEvent ev) {
    list.clear();
    list = null;
    (...)
  }
  (...)
}
```

Until now, all seems to work well. But when the user logs out from the application and my `LogoutHandler` invalidates the session by the following

```
(...)
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if (session != null) {
  session.invalidate();
}
(...)
```

the method `valueUnbound()` in object `GwgImpl` is called twice. Because the first call of the method sets the variable `list` to `null`, the second call results in a `NullPointerException`.

I know that I could easily fix this problem by adding an if-statement, but because no other applicationserver has this problem I have the following questions:

Is an applicationserver allowed to call the `valueUnbound(..)` method twice during session invalidating for an object which is bound to a session? (I haven't found a clear answer from the servlet spec, yet)

Or is this a bug in the Websphere applicationserver?

## EDIT

I modified my `valueUnbound(..)` method to see the call stacks of the two calls and the values of the `HttpSessionBindingEvent`.

```
public void valueUnbound(HttpSessionBindingEvent ev) {
  logger.info("Stacktrace:");
  for (StackTraceElement stackTraceElement : Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()) {
    logger.info("  " + stackTraceElement.toString());
  }
  logger.info("HttpSessionBindingEvent:");
  logger.info("  SessionID='" + ev.getSession().getId() + "'");
  logger.info("  Name='" + ev.getName() + "'");
  logger.info("  Value='" + ev.getValue() + "'");
  (...)
}
```

In my Websphere logfile I now find the following lines:

```
Stacktrace:
  java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Unknown Source)
  com.mycorp.gwg.dao.GwgImpl.valueUnbound(GwgImpl.java:130)
  com.ibm.ws.session.http.HttpSessionObserver.sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionObserver.java:231)
  com.ibm.ws.session.SessionEventDispatcher.sessionDestroyed(SessionEventDispatcher.java:167)
  com.ibm.ws.session.StoreCallback.sessionInvalidated(StoreCallback.java:129)
  com.ibm.ws.session.store.memory.MemorySession.invalidate(MemorySession.java:236)
  com.ibm.ws.session.http.HttpSessionImpl.invalidate(HttpSessionImpl.java:317)
  com.ibm.ws.session.SessionData.invalidate(SessionData.java:256)
  com.ibm.ws.session.HttpSessionFacade.invalidate(HttpSessionFacade.java:197)
  com.mycorp.login.client.LogoutHandler.doLogout(LogoutHandler.java:154)
  (...)
HttpSessionBindingEvent:
  SessionID='X_AmenZHphA-DBkNRoOeWZu'
  Name='gwg'
  Value='null'
(...)
Stacktrace:
  java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Unknown Source)
  com.mycorp.gwg.dao.GwgImpl.valueUnbound(GwgImpl.java:130)
  com.ibm.ws.session.http.HttpSessionAttributeObserver.sessionAttributeRemoved(HttpSessionAttributeObserver.java:160)
  com.ibm.ws.session.SessionStateEventDispatcher.sessionAttributeRemoved(SessionStateEventDispatcher.java:142)
  com.ibm.ws.session.StoreCallback.sessionAttributeRemoved(StoreCallback.java:196)
  com.ibm.ws.session.store.memory.MemorySession.removeAttribute(MemorySession.java:537)
  com.ibm.ws.session.store.memory.MemorySession.invalidate(MemorySession.java:253)
  com.ibm.ws.session.http.HttpSessionImpl.invalidate(HttpSessionImpl.java:317)
  com.ibm.ws.session.SessionData.invalidate(SessionData.java:256)
  com.ibm.ws.session.HttpSessionFacade.invalidate(HttpSessionFacade.java:197)
  com.mycorp.login.client.LogoutHandler.doLogout(LogoutHandler.java:154)
  (...)
HttpSessionBindingEvent:
  SessionID='X_AmenZHphA-DBkNRoOeWZu'
  Name='gwg'
  Value='com.mycorp.gwg.dao.GwgImpl@b294b7c'
```

Comment: did you ever find clarity on this.  I am observing a similar pattern with WAS 9 causing us an issue and trying to find best way to determine valueUnbound is called during sessionDestroyed vs sessionAttributeRemoved.  Thoughts?

Comment: @bcoveny: Unfortunately not. I ended in accepting this (for me) strange behaviour and hardened my `valueUnbound()` methods.